# Removing and prepending in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve a simple unordered list, with the following behaviour.
When a list item is clicked, it needs to go on top of the list.

I managed to do it by assigning the element to a variable, removing "this" (the clicked item) and prepending my element variable.

This seems to work. Only once.

I guess this is because the elements are removed from the DOM, and the new ones are not "detected". WHat is the right way to do it?

Here's my simple code:

```
$('ul.selekta li').on('click', function() {
  var element = $(this);
  $(this).remove();
  $('ul.selekta').prepend(element);
});
```

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Aso see `.detach()`: http://api.jquery.com/detach/ "The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time."

Comment: Also you could write `$('ul.selekta').on('click','li',function(){});`

Comment: Is this better or more efficient than what i did?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're removing the element, just prepend it :

```
$('ul.selekta li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prependTo('ul.selekta');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8d8ku/)

Comment: ahhhh thanks! I thought i needed to remove it too! I'll accept he answer asap (in 11 mins)